# How to configure Web Deploy on Windows 10 pro

Tags: iis, windows-10, microsoft-web-deploy

How can I configure Web Deploy on Windows 10? Should it work? 
I found information about Web Deploy on Windows 8, there it isn't working.
How is it in Windows 10?

Comment: I'm having this problem too, trying to run it to deploy on a dev machine with Windows 10 Pro. Web Management Service is installed and running but not listening on any port as far as I can see, so I can't connect to it. IIS management tools don't show up in IIS either and there's precious little info about the whole thing for Windows 10.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Microsoft is being super sneaky about this, but it appears they have removed the ability to use web deploy remotely from ALL non server os's.  Even in Windows 7, if you do all of the newest updates, the deploy menu vanishes in IIS.  So if you want to use web deploy it seems like your only option is to shell out some bucks for a server os.

HOWEVER, I was able to get FTP publishing configured and working on my Windows 10 machine, which works almost as well.  Just install the FTP server under control panel => programs and settings => install windows components.  Then open iis mgr and right click on your site and a configure FTP publishing option should pop up.  The configuration is a pain and not straightforward, but if you mess with it you'll figure it out.

Then in Visual Studio right click on your project, hit publish, then in the first screen in the drop down there is the good old fashioned ftp option.  Good luck!

EDIT

From OP's response, another solution is to simply share the root folder on the server, so for example

C:/inetpub/www

Then mount that share on your development box, I mounted it as the P:\ drive for production, and Q:\ drive for qa.  Then in visual studio on the publish screen just select deploy to file system and deploy to that mapped drive, works like a charm and is far simpler than setting up FTP.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. I know how to use FTP publishing. I prefer to use shared folders and deploy to folder, in my local network. It's easier.

Comment: That is another option I actually hadn't considered, lets get this documented too as I know there are a ton of noob devs frustrated as can be over this right now.  If you just share the root folder and deploy directly to that is that all you have to do?  Can you deploy to a unc path or do you have to mount the share?

Comment: I share app folder on "server", mount it locally and deploy to mounted localization.

Comment: I tried that this weekend and it's soo much simpler than setting up ftp.  It's amazing to me how often the simple things escape me...

Comment: What do you do if you cannot overwrite the contents of the mapped directory because the server process is locking some file?

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I did this (in Windows 10):

1. Uninstalled Web Deploy 3.6 from control panel(didn't help).
2. Downloaded Web Deploy 3.6 installer, then ran uninstall from the installation menu.
3. Downloaded Microsoft Web Platform Installer 5.0.
4. From the Web Platform Installer 5.0, I installed Web Deploy 3.5 + Web Deploy 3.5 without bundled SQL Support
5. I seem to have the deploy context menu back when I right click a site.

Comment: U need to have the Management service running (port 8172 DEFAULT) to accept the requests.

Comment: @HoopSnake you can run management service by `net start WMSVC` and then `sc config WMSVC start= auto` but still it's not working bcs we need to enable the remote debugging that is not available in iis

Comment: Thanks. These steps worked for me on Windows 10 Pro and I've been trying all sorts of things for weeks with no luck. I think this should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do the following:

1. Install web Deploy 3.6
2. Go to Server Manager > IIS
3. Under Server Roles go down to Web Server (IIS), expand this tree and select Management Tools.
4. Make sure "Management Service" is checked
5. Go to Services, Make sure "Web Management Services" is started.  (go ahead and make it automatic while you're in there).

Now you'll see the "Configure Web Deploy Publishing" option under the Deploy menu on IIS.  From there make sure you have port 8172 open from the IP you are publishing from.

Comment: This made the icon "IIS Manager Permissions" appear in IIS Manager for me. Thank you!

Comment: There is no Server Manager on Windows 10, though. This only work on Windows Server.

Comment: I could not find "server manager:" in windows 10. Could you please tell me how to open server manager?

Answer (score 0):

Installing WebDeploy 2.1 (available from the Web Platform Installer) gives you a 'Deploy' option on your website in Windows 10

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/253292/why-dont-i-have-deploy-actions-available-in-iis-7-manager